How can I focus on the specific ActivityBar Icon in vscode after Right-Click menu Commands run?
I create a vscode project copy-image-size with ActivityBar. But I have no idea how to focus on my ActivityBar Icon after Right-Click menu Commands run on assets directory automatically.
I tried to check the VSCode documentation but failed, and I have never seemed to do that with other projects.
step here
// my contributes field in package.json
"viewsContainers": {
  "activitybar": [
    {
      "id": "pinecone",
      "title": "PineCone Gallery",
      "icon": "media/i-pine-cone.svg"
    }
  ]
},
"views": {
  "pinecone": [
    {
      "id": "1_pineconeViews",
      "name": "",
      "type": "webview",
      "when": "copy-image-size.showPineConeGalleryIcon"
    }
  ]
},
"menus": {
  "explorer/context": [
    {
      "command": "copy-image-size.openPineCone",
      "group": "copy-image-size.pinecone@01",
      "when": "explorerResourceIsFolder"
    }]
}

